# Navigating back to root - menu toggle button broken

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2

I am using Ionic 2.

Page 1 (SearchPage) -> popover -> Page 2 (MapPage) -> Page 1 (SearchPage) (menuToggle not working)

I have a **root page** (SearchPage):

**html**

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <button menuToggle>
      <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon>
    </button>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>
```

**ts**

```
  presentPopover(event: Event): void {
    let popover: Popover = this.popoverController.create(SearchPopOverPage, {
      ev: event,
      employeeModel: this.employeeModel
    });
    popover.present();
  }
```

**Popover**

```
  presentFilterMap(event: Event) {
    this.viewCtrl.dismiss().then(() => {
      this.nav.push(MapPage, {
        ev: event,
        employeeModel: this.employeeModel,
        fromSearch: true
      })
    });
  }
```

But when I try return to the root page (with a parameter), it displays the menu toggle button (3 lines), but when I click it it does not work (i.e. does nothing, where it should display the side menu).

**ts** (MapPage) file which returns to root:

```
  this.nav.insert(0, SearchPage, {
    employeeModel: this.employeeModel
  });
```

If I try `popToRoot(options)`, this works and the menu toggle button is working. However, it does not reload the page with the new parameter.

Any ideas how I should navigate back to the root page with a parameter please?

Thanks

UPDATE:
I have tried the following, but it does not go back to the root:

```
  let options = {
    employeeModel: this.employeeModel
  };
  this.nav.popToRoot(options);
```

UPDATE:
I have also tried changing the popovers call to the next page, but with little success. Now the back button on the MapPage works, but when I go to the root page, the menuToggle is still not responding to clicks.

```
  presentFilterMap(event: Event) {
    this.nav.push(MapPage, {
      employeeModel: this.employeeModel,
      fromSearch: true
    }).then(() => {
      this.viewCtrl.dismiss();
    });
  }
```

If I don't dismiss the popover,

```
    this.nav.push(MapPage, {
      employeeModel: this.employeeModel,
      fromSearch: true
    });
```

then when I use the back button on the MapPage back to root, the popover is still there, and the menuToggle works as expected. But if I rather navigate back to the root page (which I need to do) then the popover is not there and the menuToggle is not responsive.

This means the issue is to do with the popover.

Comment: I think my problem is related to the popover, because the Page 2 (MapPage) menuToggle does not work either. So once the button on the popover is clicked, I think it is messing with the navigation. Just a guess.

Comment: I have looked at my Ionic 2 code. Try doing exactly has they had pre-installed with the menu, changing the root to avoid the back arrow. `this.nav.setRoot(SearchPage);`

Comment: theblindprophet, sorry for taking ages to respond. `this.nav.setRoot(SearchPage);` tales me to the `SearchPage`, but with the same issue, the menuToggle button does not work. It makes me think that the issue is because I have a `popover` in between. I think that is 'breaking' it somehow.

Answer (score 3):

```
 import { App } from 'ionic-angular';

constuctor(public app: App) {};

pushSignupPage() {
    this.viewCtrl.dismiss().then(() => {
      this.app.getRootNav().push(SignupPage);
    });
  }
```

this work for me. good luck

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. Please read this [how-to-answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) for providing quality answer.

Comment: Working like a charm ;)

Answer (score 1):

SOLUTION: Use events to handle the parameters and pop to root

```
 let data = {
    eModel: this.eModel
  };
events.publish('employee:update', data);
this.nav.popToRoot();
```

In your SearchPage constructor:

```
events.subscribe('employee:update', (data) => {
//do whatever you need to do with your data:
  let EModel = data[0].eModel;
});
```

Comment: Since you're passing data, would not be better if you create a dataService, and use *observables* to subscribe to it? The result would be the same, but I guess using a service is a better way to handle applicaton's data than using events. If you want I can add an answer with more details.

Answer (score 0):

when you navigate back from map page to search page

use :

```
  this.navCtrl.push(SearchPage, { employeeModel: this.employeeModel });
```